# The way to differ thrown and swallowed exception and an error written to the pipeline

Tags: powershell

Given the function that receives Powershell code as a text and execute it:

```
function Exec
{
    param(
        [string]$expression
    )

    $Error.Clear()
    $Result = $Null

    try
    {
        $Result = Invoke-Expression $expression
    }
    catch {
        $Result = $_
        $Error.Clear()
    }
    finally
    {
        if($Error.Count -gt 0)
        {
            $Result = $Error[0]
        }
    }
    Write-Host $Result
}
```

Three types of expressions might be passed to this function:

```
$expression1 = "try {throw 'some exception'}catch {'some result'}"

$expression2 = "throw 'another exception'"

$expression3 = "Write-Error 'something went wrong...'"
```

When I pass the first one I would like "some result" to be printed, however I'll see "some exception" instead of this, because $result was rewritten in Finally block.

Is there any way to print actual result, but not the last error here and not break down working of this code with other two types of expressions?

Answer (score 1):

It would make things more clear if OP specified desired behavior in the various cases you are trying to handle, rather than giving a set of 3 (what are essentially) unit tests. Having 3 unit tests is problematic because: 1) the person answering the question has to reverse engineer the desired behavior by first guessing at what the 3 unit tests are supposed to yield and second by guessing what behavior that result implies and 2) 3 unit tests aren't enough to cover the gamut of behaviors (if I'm guessing the intended behaviors correctly).

The gamut of behaviors I'm guessing are: 1) expression executes without errors, 2) expression executes with one non-terminating error, 3) expression executes with multiple non-terminating errors, 4) a terminating error, 5) a single non-terminating error and a terminating error, 6) multiple non-terminating errors and a terminating error

With that said how about this:

```
function Exec
{
    param(
        [string]$expression
    )

    # Not usually necessary to clear $error but could be done here if
    # really necessary, by uncommenting next line
    # $error.clear()

    $preErrorCount = $postErrorCount = $Error.count
    $Result = $Null

    # If $expression executes without errors, then $result is value of
    #  $expression. If a terminating error occurs, then $result is the 
    #  ErrorRecord that caused the termination. If only non-terminating error(s)
    #  occurred then $result is $error[0] (most recent non-terminating error)
    try
    {
        $Result = Invoke-Expression $expression
    }
    catch {
        $Result = $_
        $postErrorCount = $Error.count
    }

    if($Error.Count -ne $preErrorCount) {
        # Either (or both) terminating and/or non-terminating error occurred
        if ($postErrorCount -ne $preErrorCount) {
            # Terminating error occurred. $Result is already set correctly, nothing to do
        } else {
            # Only non-terminating error(s) occurred, copy most recent
            $result = $error[0]
        }
    }
    # In the OP $Result is not returned by function, only written to host
    # Preserving that behavior
    Write-Host $Result

    # NOTE: in OP script does not clear $error if non-terminating error occurs
    #   but clears it if terminating error occurs. Probably a bug.

    # Uncomment following if $error should be cleared on both terminating and
    # non-terminating errors before returning to caller. (In general callers
    # of PS cmds shouldn't assume $error is cleared or preserved across the call)
    # $error.clear() 
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but, unfortunately it works with $expression1 not as I expected. It prints 'some exception', but I want to see 'some result' in case of a handled exception.

Comment: Hopefully it was instructive in terms of asking questions on SO that can be more readily and easily answered.

Answer (score 0):

This function works as I want:

```
function Exec
{
param(
    [string]$expression
)

$Error.Clear()
$Result = $Null

try
{
    $Result = Invoke-Expression $expression -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    $Result = $_
}

Write-Host $Result
}
```

Comment: So if `$expression` generates a non-terminating error(s) you turn it into a terminating error and stop processing. That detail was also not in the OP.